# GIT rm is deleting top level directory

Tags: git

below is directory structure:

```
Top_dir
--test_file
```

Now when I do git rm test_file, since Top_dir does not have any other files git is deleting Top_dir aswell. Is it normal behaviour of git?

Comment: Yes, git only cares about files, not directories. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Git doesn't use a filesystem exactly. It uses "blobs". There's an article called [git from the bottom up](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf) which is reasonably short and highly recommended. Here's a relevant snippet:

> The diﬀerence between a Git blob and a ﬁlesystem’s ﬁle is that a blob
>   stores no metadata about its content. All such information is kept in
>   the tree that holds the blob. Onetree may know those contents as a ﬁle
>   named “foo” that was created in August 2004, while another tree may
>   know the same contents as a ﬁle named “bar” that was created ﬁve years later.
>   In a normal filesystem, two ﬁles with the same contents but with such
>   diﬀerent metadata would always be represented as two independent ﬁles.
>   Why this difference? Mainly, it’s because a filesystem is designed to
>   support files that change, whereas Git is not. The fact that data is immutable in
>   the Git repository is what makes all of this work and so a diﬀerent
>   design was needed. And as it turns out, this design allows for much
>   more compact storage, since all objects having identical content can be
>   shared, no matter where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not really sure if git does that. It deletes files from your current working tree /index and staging area.

http://gitref.org/basic/#rm-mv

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html

If you are a beginner with git , i suggest using gitk ( which provides a nice user interface to git repository ) making this easier. You can install that from terminal as sudo.

Hope that helps !